# change path of storing audio in react native (File not exist on the path)

Tags: react-native

i have follow this link 
https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio
 for audio recoder and audio player.The problem is i am unable to change the path of storing audio in my device(mobile). How can i change the path.In that link path is set using this line 
audioPath: AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.aac'

I want to store the audio inside my app like watsapp audio chat. Please guide me i am new to React-native